# Flutter: JSON Loop

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I have a Json parsing project in Flutter and the Json is as follows:

```
{
  "Dependents":[
      {
        "Name": "Kim",
        "Relationship": "Parent",
        "Entitlements": [
            {
              "GP": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            },
            {
              "OPS": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            },
            {
              "IP": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            },
            {
              "Dental": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            },
            {
              "Optical": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            },
            {
              "Maternity": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Tim",
        "Relationship": "Spouse",
        "Entitlements": [
            {
              "GP": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            },
            {
              "OPS": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            },
            {
              "IP": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            },
            {
              "Maternity": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Lim",
        "Relationship": "Child",
        "Entitlements": [
            {
              "GP": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            },
            {
              "OPS": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            },
            {
              "Dental": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            },
            {
              "Optical": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            },
            {
              "Maternity": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Xim",
        "Relationship": "Child",
        "Entitlements": [
            {
              "GP": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            },
            {
              "OPS": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            },
            {
              "IP": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, under the **Dependents** there are multiple users and under those users they have their own **Entitlements**.

**The problem I am having currently is:**

How do I loop through the **Entitlements** to print out all the maps under that since every user has different **Entitlements** associated with them.

Kindly assist.

Comment: A very broad question, but here you'll probably find some answers https://flutter.io/json/

Answer (score 29):

You could use the following snippet:

```
  void iterateJson(String jsonStr) {
    Map<String, dynamic> myMap = json.decode(jsonStr);
    List<dynamic> entitlements = myMap["Dependents"][0]["Entitlements"];
    entitlements.forEach((entitlement) {
      (entitlement as Map<String, dynamic>).forEach((key, value) {
        print(key);
        (value as Map<String, dynamic>).forEach((key2, value2) {
          print(key2);
          print(value2);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Although you could possibly simplify a little the 'entitlements' field if you don't care about the order by removing the list and leaving just one map:

```
"Entitlements": {
              "GP": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              },
              "OPS": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              },
              "IP": {
                "Entitlement": "10000",
                "Utilisation": "500",
                "Balance": "9500"
              }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try. But where do i set the url in the iterateJson method?

Comment: Because I am using a future builder in the class that parses this JSON.

Comment: Well, in your question you asked for a way to iterate the `entitlements`, and this is one way to do it. We lack perspective of your application. If your future returns the json string you can parse the string inside the future builder and build your widgets from there.

Answer (score 7):

You have information there : http://cogitas.net/parse-json-dart-flutter/

Example from the page :

```
void _parseJsonForCrossword(String jsonString) {
Map decoded = JSON.decode(jsonString);

String name = decoded['name'];
 print(name);

 int id = decoded['id'];
 print(id.toString());

 for (var word in decoded['across']) {
   print(word['number'].toString());
   print(word['word']);
 }
}
```