# Handling JSON as String in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've tried to fetch a list of teachers:

In provider Teacher I have:

```
Future<void> getTeachers() async {
    final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/teachers/";
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.encode(json.decode(response.body));
      final List<Teacher> loadedTeachers = [];

      extractedData.forEach((teacherId, teacherData) {
        loadedTeachers.add(Teacher(
          id: teacherData["uuid"],
          firstname: teacherData["firstname"],
          lastname: teacherData["lastname"],
          location: teacherData["location"],
          imageUrl: "",
          isActive: true,
          isFavorite: false,
        ));
      });
      _coaches = loadedCoaches;

 

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

But after encode the response.body, It returns back a String therefore I can't iterate through it like **extractedTeachers.forEach** to create an object of Teacher for each one. How should I handle this?

UPDATE:
Sample of JSON

```
[
    {
        "uuid": "b1bcfc7b-a847-4069-ba76-a4bf274d95e9",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email": "JD@gmail.com",
        "is_active": true,
        "profile": null
    },
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: JSON Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52034895/flutter-json-loop)

Comment: Can you post a sample json.

Comment: @SagarAcharya I've updated the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check out the example that I have made for you :

Below is the json you provided:

```
[
    {
        "uuid": "b1bcfc7b-a847-4069-ba76-a4bf274d95e9",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email": "JD@gmail.com",
        "is_active": true,
        "profile": null
    }
]
```

model class for the json :

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final teachers = teachersFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<Teachers> teachersFromJson(String str) => List<Teachers>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Teachers.fromJson(x)));

String teachersToJson(List<Teachers> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Teachers {
    Teachers({
        this.uuid,
        this.firstName,
        this.lastName,
        this.email,
        this.isActive,
        this.profile,
    });

    String uuid;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String email;
    bool isActive;
    dynamic profile;

    factory Teachers.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Teachers(
        uuid: json["uuid"],
        firstName: json["first_name"],
        lastName: json["last_name"],
        email: json["email"],
        isActive: json["is_active"],
        profile: json["profile"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "uuid": uuid,
        "first_name": firstName,
        "last_name": lastName,
        "email": email,
        "is_active": isActive,
        "profile": profile,
    };
}
```

And below is the implementation:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:json_parsing_example/models.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Index(),
    );
  }
}

class Index extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IndexState createState() => _IndexState();
}



class _IndexState extends State<Index> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Text('sample'),
    );
  }

  Future<String> fetchData() async {
    String data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/parse.json");
  // this is using the model
    final teachers = teachersFromJson(data);
    print('This is the list of Strings ${teachers.length}');

/* "uuid": "b1bcfc7b-a847-4069-ba76-a4bf274d95e9",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email": "JD@gmail.com",
        "is_active": true,
        "profile": null */

        // this below using using the map iteration

    List<Teacher> teacherList = List();

    final jsonResult = json.decode(data);
    jsonResult.forEach((element) {
      Teacher teacher = Teacher(
        id: element['uuid'],
        firstname: element['first_name'],
        lastname: element['last_name'],
        email: element['email'],
        isActive: element['is_active'],
        profile: element['profile'],
      );

      teacherList.add(teacher);
    });

    print('This is map iterated list for teacher ${teacherList.length}');

   
    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }



}





class Teacher {
  final String id;
  final String firstname;
  final String lastname;
  final String email;
  final bool isActive;
  final String profile;

  Teacher(
      {this.id,
      this.firstname,
      this.lastname,
      this.email,
      this.isActive,
      this.profile});
}
```

I have done in both ways using the model and using the map iteration just check it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks. I have problem with the code. I separated my Model as Teacher and Provider as Teachers. inside Teacher as you may guess I just return an object of Teacher, However in provider Teachers I fetch my data there. I don't write logic in my widget. When data is returning for each item in fetched data I append to the list loadedTeacher and at the end of the loop and set _teachers = loadedTeacher then call the notifyListener() to display them on my widget.

Comment: That's great. so its working now right you solved it on your own. Was my answer helpful.  if not so that i can delete it. Let me know.

Comment: Yeah thank you. If someone doesn’t represent better answer I will confirm. Thanks again.