# Iterate a Json parsed http response in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I get an http response. Then I parse it.
My problem is how to iterate the json parsed response in a `for` loop

```
     final response =
     await http.get('http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/getetab');
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       var parsedJson = json.decode(response.body);
       print(parsedJson) ;

       return parsedJson ;
     } else {
       throw Exception('Failed to load');
     }
```

this is the parsedJson print result :

```
[{id: 1, nom: violette, adresse: tunis, categorie: coiffeuse, createdAt: 2020-08-05T12:10:10.000Z, updatedAt: 2020-08-05T12:10:10.000Z}, {id: 2, nom: soho, adresse: ariena, categorie: coiffeuse, createdAt: 2020-08-05T12:10:10.000Z, updatedAt: 2020-08-05T12:10:10.000Z}]
```

How to iterate 'parsedJson' in a for loop?

Comment: What do you actually wanna do after it, i mean, there can be other easier alternatives too.

Comment: i want just to iterate parsedJson into a for loop but i can't find the parsedJson.length

Comment: This might help,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52034895/flutter-json-loop

Comment: Can you please post how the json looks like? Then we can help you.

Comment: @NiklasLehnfeld please check the post i added the print result of parsedjson

Answer (score 1):

1. I assume you missed the quotes in the json. Should look like:

```
"[{\"id\": 1, \"nom\": \"violette\", \"adresse\": \"tunis\", \"categorie\": \"coiffeuse\", \"createdAt\": \"2020-08-05T12:10:10.000Z\", \"updatedAt\": \"2020-08-05T12:10:10.000Z\"}, {\"id\": 2, \"nom\": \"soho\", \"adresse\": \"ariena\", \"categorie\": \"coiffeuse\", \"createdAt\": \"2020-08-05T12:10:10.000Z\", \"updatedAt\": \"2020-08-05T12:10:10.000Z\"}]";
```

2. When you put this json above into the `json.decode(String)` method it will return you a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`. You can iterate over this with a simple `forEach`-Loop.

```
String jsonString =
        "[{\"id\": 1, \"nom\": \"violette\", \"adresse\": \"tunis\", \"categorie\": \"coiffeuse\", \"createdAt\": \"2020-08-05T12:10:10.000Z\", \"updatedAt\": \"2020-08-05T12:10:10.000Z\"}, {\"id\": 2, \"nom\": \"soho\", \"adresse\": \"ariena\", \"categorie\": \"coiffeuse\", \"createdAt\": \"2020-08-05T12:10:10.000Z\", \"updatedAt\": \"2020-08-05T12:10:10.000Z\"}]";
    

List<dynamic> data = json.decode(jsonString);

data.forEach((entry) {
  int id = entry["id"];
  String nom = entry["nom"];
  String adresse = entry["adresse"];

  print("id: $id, nom: $nom, adresse: $adresse");
});
```